# VBA - Get Cell Values from other workbook without opening

Tags: vba, cell, excel

I'm working to get the cell value of other workbook without opening it.

And here's some of my codes:

`Range("F3")= "='C:\inetpub\vhosts\hotdogko.com\httpdocs\private\excel\[Launch Pad.xls]Sheet1'!$B$12 "`

This code is working well when data type of the cell value to pull is Date, Integer or Any not String data type. But it wont work correctly to string data type, it just returning #N/A.

Thanks for someone who can give me an answer for this problem.

Comment: You have an equals sign (=) which is telling Excel that what follows is a formula or numeric. Try removing the equals sign.

Comment: Removing the = sign don't help. it return the string formula

Answer (score 5):

You can try with following answer

```
Sub ReadDataFromAnotherWorkBook()

    ' Open Workbook A with specific location
    Dim src As Workbook
    Set src = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\chan.yoonghon\Desktop\Excel\BookA.xlsx", True, True)

    Dim valueBookA As Integer
    Dim valueBookB As Integer

    valueBookA = src.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
    Cells(1, 1).Value = valueBookA

    ' Close Workbooks A
    src.Close False
    Set src = Nothing

     ' Dialog Answer
    MsgBox valueBookA
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add the text function after the equal It should work something like:

```
Range("F3")= "=text("'C:\inetpub\vhosts\hotdogko.com\httpdocs\private\excel\[Launch Pad.xls]Sheet1'!$B$12 " ;"") "
```

Perhaps you should check if the `"` are correct because sometimes you have to add double `""`.

Answer (score -1):

Try it without using quotation marks (" "). It should help.