# based on contents of cell, move a file to another folder

Tags: excel

I have 3 identical xlsx attachments from the same sender.  I have appended date time and random number to save each file.  Now I need to apply one of 3 `.bat` files (all slightly different) according to the contents of `B1` in the attached xlsx.
What I was thinking of doing was finding the value of `B1` and depending on it move the file to a specific folder.  The file starts off in folder 'data'.

Criteria and target folders are:

> If B1 = "D01" then change location to c:\temp\dataBW
>   If B1 = "D10" then change location to c:\temp\dataDC
>   If B1 = "D20" then change location to c:\temp\dataDO

All folders already exist.

Comment: How is it going then? For inspiration, see [google search: excel vba move file](https://www.google.sk/search?q=excel+vba+move+file&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ePNbWMeyNZLZ8AfZub8o)

Comment: the problem I have is with checking b1 and making the decision based on it

Comment: So you need 1. [excel vba list files in folder](https://www.google.sk/search?q=excel+vba+list+files+in+folder&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=E_dbWJ_6H4LZ8AeXgJ3gBQ), 2. [open all xlsx files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx), 3. Check `B1` and decide based on logic in your question.

Comment: do I have to a) list the files b) open the files?  i do not want to change the contents of the file, just move them.  Sorry if I am being thick!

Comment: The `B1` you want to check is in the "3 identical .xlsx"? Can you please clarify this point. If it is so, then you need to get to the `B1`'s somehow, opening xlsx's is one of them. To open them, you need to know which to open, so list them first. If you only need syntax help with the `IF condition` look on [TechNet for example](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php)

Comment: You can maybe try a workaround [SO-VBA - Get Cell Values from other workbook without opening](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192610/vba-get-cell-values-from-other-workbook-without-opening)

Comment: I have 3 files in 1 folder.  Each file has a different value in B1. I want to use the value in B1 to change the path of that file so that I can save/move the file in another folder. And I need to loop through the original folder.  Does this make more sense?

Comment: It certainly does! Specific, with just the one problem at hand, focused. This should be the text of the question itself + necessary details you already provided (leave the date, random; clarify the .bat). You can edit the question to get better answers. I really recommend doing that. **About solution:** Did you try any of the steps in [my previous comment(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285615/based-on-contents-of-cell-move-a-file-to-another-folder?noredirect=1#comment69776954_41285615)? Do you need help with those?